# How to get a variable into the key of an object?

Tags: javascript

I've got the following and say I have four repos being input `[first, second, third, fourth]`

```
this.getLanguagesFromRepo = function(username, siteAndPassword, repo) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get('https://api.github.com/repos/' + username + '/' + repo + '/languages', {
            auth: { username: username, password: siteAndPassword.password}
        })
        .then((response) => {
            resolve({ repo: response.data })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            reject(error)
        })
    })
}
```

When it's run you get

```
{ repo: { JavaScript: ... }}
{ repo: { JavaScript: ... }}
{ repo: { JavaScript: ... }}
{ repo: { JavaScript: ... }}
```

And not

```
{ first: { JavaScript: ... }}
{ second: { JavaScript: ... }}
{ third: { JavaScript: ... }}
{ fourth: { JavaScript: ... }}
```

There's an issue with `{ repo: response.data }` where it's interpreting `repo` as the word repo and not the `repo` variable in the function parameters.

How do I get the correct reference?

Comment: I'd like to add that it's more conventional to resolve the promise like this: `resolve(response.data)`. I haven't looked at the response but I'm guessing that it already has something equivalent `response.data.repo` which is more likely to be called `response.data.name` or `response.data.slug`, or something along those lines. The point is that you're unlikely to need to set the data as a prop of `{[repo]:...}`.

Comment: @maxhallinan It doesn't, it's the GitHub API - it's just the languages associated, but thanks :)

Comment: Ah you're right. That's disappointing.

Comment: Sort of - I kind of like it, I'm sick of APIs returning eeeeeverything plus the thing you requested. If I want the languages listed in a repo, that's all I want - everything else I'll code in. Y'know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the computed property syntax: `{[repo]: response.data}` if you're using ES6 or

```
    .then((response) => {
        var repoData = {};
        repoData[repo] = response.data;
        resolve(repoData);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an environment that supports it, you can use the newer object literal syntax:

```
resolve({ [repo]: response.data })
```

If not, then you'll need to do something like this:

```
var o = {};
o[repo] = response.data;
resolve(o);
```

Comment: Wow, our answers were amazingly similar. :-) Yours came first, so I'll delete mine.